# Hibernate one-to-one mapping maps incorrectly

Tags: hibernate

**Simplifying for clarity**

Lets say I have 2 tables like so:

**TableName** Building
  **(2)Columns:**
*buildPrimaryKey,
*addrForeignKey

**TableName** Address
  **(1)Columns:**
*addrPrimaryKey

I would like to have hibernate map 
Building.*addrForeignKey* to Address.addrPrimaryKey

Instead hibernate is mapping 
Building.*buildPrimaryKey* to Address.addrPrimaryKey

Current map files below
**Building.hbm.xml**
......
`<one-to-one name="addrForeignKey" fetch="select" class="com.Address"/>`
......

**Address.hbm.xml**
......
`<id name="addrPrimaryKey" type="java.lang.Long" column="addrPrimaryKey">

    <generator class="increment"/>

      </id>`
......

What am I missing or have incorrectly defined?

**Looking at similar stack overflow questions I've tried inverting the one-to-one element but get cant parse mapping errors when doing so.

Comment: Show your bean classes please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this ultimately by using a many-to-one mapping (despite that not being the actual relationship)
In Building.hbm.xml
<many-to-one name="var_addr"       **--the variable name of the contained class**
class="com.Address"                       **--class of the object in Building above**
column="addrForeignKey"                   **--the relevant foreign key**
cascade="save-update"                     **-- not sure what this does honestly**
unique="true"/>                           **--hackish way to enforce one-to-one mapping**
Address.hbm.xml -- needed no information related to this mapping
Altogether I've found object to object mapping to be very unintuitive with hibernate (in this case and actual many-to-one or many-to-many mappings), and books I have available, like the one suggesting this many-to-one mapping as a work around, seem to agree. I might try annotations in the future, hopefully they are more clear.